# Exporting data from Access to an already existing Excel spreadsheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba, export, ms-access-2007

How can I export a table from MS Access 2007 into an already existing excel spreadsheet? (Not a new spreadsheet)

The idea being that I have several macros set up on other excel sheets which will analyse the data and output graphs that I can't work out how to produce on Access.

I want to export table "Master" to:

Excel file name: "Resource Planning"

Sheet name: "Raw Data"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you not just setup a data connection and then within your macros, refresh the data when run?

Comment: That's a good idea! How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Take a look at this article http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-edit-and-manage-connections-to-external-data-HA010167227.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can create Name Ranges in Excel by going to the Formulas tab and providing a name and reference. Make sure the reference, for example: =Sheet1!$A$1; refers to the range where you want your data to be pasted. Try not to have the Excel file open while you run the subroutine. Then when you are exporting from Access you can use a vba module to run the following:

```
Private Sub ExportMyQueryOtTableToExcel()
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        "sqYourQueryNameOrTable", "x:\ExcelFile.xls", -1, "NameRangeInExcelWorkBook"
End Sub
```

If you want to run this from a Module, just change the "Private Sub" part to "Public Function". That way you can call the function from the Macro with the RunCode action (Function name = ExportMyQueryOtTableToExcel()).

Comment: Hey - it's not working. The sheet (NameRaneInExcelWorkBook) is still there but a new sheet (NameRaneInExcelWorkBook1)  gets created and the dta gets exported to that new sheet.